# How to find a function which intersects x axis on 1, y axis on a, has an area of b unit square

Tags: calculus, integration

I have created so many (thousands of) levels for a mobile game and they are sorted by difficulty. I need to group them by sections and need to find a good distribution algorithm.

Every section should have easy and hard levels, last levels of a section should be harder than the easier levels of the next session, the average difficulty of sections should increase gradually

I have reached into a conclusion that I need a function which has following properties:

***a** = number of total levels*

***b** = number of levels in a section*

$f(0) = 1$

$f(a) = 0$

$\int_0^a f(x)dx = b$

So, I can pick the required levels by this function.

Then I will remove the selected levels, update **a** with the remaining levels, run the algorithm again.

Is there an easy way to find a function like that?
Or do you think there would be a better way to find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a>0, b>0, b \le a$. There is infinite number of functions that satisfy the conditions. Let's take a polynomial of the second degree: $f(x)=cx^2+dx+1$. Obviously, $f(0)=1$. 
Using that $f(a)=0$ we get $a^2c+ad=-1$. 
Using the area constraint we get: $\frac{a^3}{3}c+\frac{a^2}{2}d+a=b$.
So we have a system of linear equations with two variables, solving it we get $c=-\frac{6b}{a^3}+\frac{3}{2a^2}$, $d=\frac{6b}{a^2}-\frac{5}{2a}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to share the results. Surprisingly, function value goes negative after around **0.8*a**, and the second root of the equation hits **a** again. This makes the absolute area over 1 because of the area under x axis.  So the algorithm picks more values than it should. I am not sure about the behavior of cubic or more complex polynomial functions now. (I am planning to give up about the area constraint and use a variation of Gaussian Distribution function)